# Can I access the DLC new content features in the main campaign?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I read that the Blood and Wine expansion adds mutations to the character page

I was planning on purchasing the DLC after finishing the main game, but if I can access the new features before finishing it then I might just purchase it sooner.

Are the new stories, quests, and mechanics in the 2 DLCs accessible before finishing the main wild hunt campaign or do you unlock them after (I assume, having finished it yet) defeating the wild hunt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are available before finishing the campaign, however Blood & Wine is very high level (Minimum Level ~35, Hearts of Stone has a minimum Level of ~29 and you will be 28-30 after finishing the main story), so they are designed to be played after finishing the main story. You can use the additional features some way into the expansions.

So, if you do them before finishing the main story, you will grossly overlevel the battle against the wild hunt (you can expect to be Level 45-50 after Blood & Wine). I recommend finishing the main campaign, then Hearts of Stone then Blood & Wine, this will be smoothest transition.

Comment: I'm already level 29 and did not reach Kaer Morhen yet... from what you say I'm already over leveled :(

Comment: @juan You are, but don't worry about it. Those are just recommended levels and you don't lose much from being overleveled.

Comment: @juan If you do everything, you can reach around maximum level 31 from the main game content. Possibly 32 if you do a lot of grinding as well. The levels are minimum levels though. Hearts of Stone is lvl 31-38, You can reach up to level 39 within it. And Blood & Wine is 37-50, you can reach around level 52 maximum.

Comment: I think I was level 26 before Kaer Morhen and 30 after the battle. 34 after finishing the game. This after roughly 100 hours though, doing all side missions, witcher contracts and treasure hunts I found. Level definitely doesn't cap at 32, I don't have any DLC yet.

Comment: I suppose having a bonus xp from monster trophy on Roach while taking on the various bosses in the latter stages might give you buckets of extra xp, also.